# Can model instances in a Rails app be modified by other DB connections while they're being inspected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm diving into Rails 4 and I'm trying to understand how to safely access model data while it's being accessed by multiple DB connections. I have some match-making logic that finds the oldest user in a queue, removes that user from the queue, and returns the user...

```
# UserQueue.rb
class UserQueue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users

  def match_user(user)
    match = nil
    if self.users.count > 0
      oldest = self.users.oldest_in_queue 
      if oldest.id != user.id
        self.users.delete(oldest)
        match = oldest
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If two different threads executed this `match_user` method around the same time, is it possible for them to both find the same `oldest` user and try to delete it from the queue, and return it to the caller? If so, how do I prevent that?

I looked into transactions, but they don't seem to be a solution since there's only one model being modified in this case (the queue).

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord has support for row locking.

This is taken from the [Rails guide, locking records for update](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update):

> **11.1 Optimistic Locking**
>
> Optimistic locking allows multiple users to access the same record for edits, and assumes a minimum of conflicts with the data. It does this by checking whether another process has made changes to a record since it was opened. An `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError` exception is thrown if that has occurred and the update is ignored.
>
> **Optimistic locking column**
>
> In order to use optimistic locking, the table needs to have a column called `lock_version` of type integer. Each time the record is updated, Active Record increments the `lock_version` column. If an update request is made with a lower value in the `lock_version` field than is currently in the `lock_version` column in the database, the update request will fail with an `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError`. Example:

```
c1 = Client.find(1)
c2 = Client.find(1)

c1.first_name = "Michael"
c1.save

c2.name = "should fail"
c2.save # Raises an ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
```

> You're then responsible for dealing with the conflict by rescuing the exception and either rolling back, merging, or otherwise apply the business logic needed to resolve the conflict.
>
> This behavior can be turned off by setting `ActiveRecord::Base.lock_optimistically = false`.
>
> To override the name of the `lock_version` column, `ActiveRecord::Base` provides a class attribute called `locking_column`:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.locking_column = :lock_client_column
end
```

I suggest reading this [section in the Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update).

Comment: Thanks, Substantial. If I understand this correctly, it sounds like I just need to wrap my code in a begin/rescue block and add the business logic needed to handle the case where the queue is modified the second time? Also, after reading the guide, it looks like I could use "Pessimistic" locking as well and just wrap the code in a transaction and call lock! on self (the queue instance)? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that absolutely could happen.  How you prevent it depends on the rest of your app/framework/database/etc.

Transactions won't help because two clients could start the request at the same time and both would see the same UserQueue record as oldest.

You want a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion).  But a mutex in the code isn't ideal if there are other ways to modify the data (ie. directly via SQL, etc.)  It can also get messy as the first time you forget to use the mutex, you've opened up the race condition.  Then again, maybe this is enough.  Just remember your mutex needs to work across threads and processes, etc.

You might see if your database has a mutex or other row level lock you can use to mark the oldest queue record, then extract it.

Or find another way to grab the oldest queue that avoids the race condition entirely.  Something like:

- SQL to update the oldest queue whose id is not user.id and set "marked_for_work" to some unique ID.
- Fetch the queue row whose marked_for_work value is our unique ID.

You could run multiple threads with the above without worry as the SQL update is (well, it should be!) atomic.